# Implement a vertical UIScrollView with constraints

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I need to put more content in the `UIView` but I'm not sure how to implement a `UIScrollView` to put much more content, and this only scrolls horizontally.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    /*DECLARACION DE OBJETOS*/


    //Declaracion del Label
    let Titulo = UILabel() as UILabel;
    let Titulo_Clima = UILabel() as UILabel;
    let Texto = UILabel() as UILabel;

    let texto_Titulo = "Hola.";
    let texto_Inicio = "Bienvenidos a Robinsonia, esta aplicacón te ayudará a organizar tu viaje a Robinson Crusoe, selecciona las opciones en el menu principal, haciendo clic en el boton superior izquierdo.";

    let texto_Clima = "Clima";

    /*FIN DECLARACION DE OBJETOS*/


    //FUNCION PARA PERMITIR COLORES HEXÁDECIMALES
    func uicolorFromHex(rgbValue:UInt32)->UIColor{
        let red = CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16)/256.0;
        let green = CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8)/256.0;
        let blue = CGFloat(rgbValue & 0xFF)/256.0;

        return UIColor(red:red, green:green, blue:blue, alpha:1.0);
    }
    //***

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

         //ITEM QUE ABRE EL MENU.
        title = "Crusoe";
        view.backgroundColor = uicolorFromHex(0xD9E5EA);

        //Imagen icono menu principal
        let b3 = UIBarButtonItem(image:UIImage(named:"Menu"), style:.Plain, target:self, action:"presentLeftMenuViewController");
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = b3;

        //Color de Fuente
        let fuente_titulo = UIFont (name: "Oxygen", size: 35);
        let fuente_tituloClima = UIFont (name: "Oxygen", size: 26);
        let fuente_texto = UIFont (name: "Oxygen", size: 17);
        let color_fuente_texo = uicolorFromHex(0x484A4B);
        let color_fuente_titulos = uicolorFromHex(0x3A3B3C);

        //**** Logica de contenido
        let button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton;
        button.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 100);
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor();
        button.setTitle("Test Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal);
        button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside);

        //Dibujo el Label.
        Titulo.text = texto_Titulo;
        Titulo.font = fuente_titulo
        Titulo.textAlignment = .Center;
        Titulo.textColor = color_fuente_titulos;
        Titulo.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false);

        //Dibujo el titulo del clima
        Titulo_Clima.text = texto_Clima;
        Titulo_Clima.font = fuente_tituloClima;
        Titulo_Clima.textAlignment = .Left;
        Titulo_Clima.textColor = color_fuente_titulos;
        Titulo_Clima.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false);

        //Dibujo texto de inicio.
        Texto.text = texto_Inicio;
        Texto.font = fuente_texto;
        Texto.textAlignment = .Center;
        Texto.textColor = color_fuente_texo;
        Texto.numberOfLines=6;
        Texto.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false);

        //*** DEFINIENDO EL COLOR DEL BORDER
        let borderColor : UIColor = uicolorFromHex(0xFFFFFF);

        //*** VIEW SUPERIOR
        var topView = UIView();
        topView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false);

        //*** VIEW UNO
        var bottomView = UIView();
        //bottomView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.1);
        bottomView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false);


        //*** VIEW DOS
        var bottomView_dos = UIView();
        bottomView_dos.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.1);
        bottomView_dos.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false);



        //*** DEFNIENDO LOS OBJETOS CON 0 OPACIDAD
        Titulo.alpha = 0;
        Texto.alpha = 0;
        bottomView.alpha = 0;
        bottomView_dos.alpha = 0;


        //*** INICIALIZANDO LOS VIEWS
        self.view.addSubview(topView);
        self.view.addSubview(bottomView);
        self.view.addSubview(bottomView_dos);

        //*** TEXTOS
        topView.addSubview(Titulo); // titulo del inicio
        topView.addSubview(Texto); // texto del inicio
        bottomView.addSubview(Titulo_Clima); // titulo del clima


        //*** DEFINIENDO LAS ANIMACIONES PARA LOS OBJETOS
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {
            self.Titulo.alpha = 1.0
            bottomView.alpha = 2.0
            bottomView_dos.alpha = 3.0
        })

        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5, animations: {
            self.Texto.alpha = 1.0
        })

        //*** DICCIONARIO
        let viewsDictionary = ["top":topView
                                ,"bottom":bottomView
                                ,"bottom_dos":bottomView_dos
                                ,"button":button
                                ,"Titulo":Titulo
                                ,"Texto":Texto
                                ,"Titulo_Clima":Titulo_Clima]


        //*** POSICION DE LOS VIEWS HORIZONTAL
        let view_constraint_H:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-10-[top]-10-|",
                                                                                        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0),
                                                                                        metrics: nil,
                                                                                        views: viewsDictionary)
        let view_constraint_H2:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-10-[bottom(bottom_dos)]-[bottom_dos]-10-|",
                                                                                        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0),
                                                                                        metrics: nil,
                                                                                        views: viewsDictionary)

            view.addConstraints(view_constraint_H as [AnyObject])
            view.addConstraints(view_constraint_H2 as [AnyObject])

        //*** POSICION DE LOS VIEWS VERTICAL
        let view_constraint_V:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-65-[top(bottom)]-[bottom]-10-|",
                                                                                        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllLeading,
                                                                                        metrics: nil,
                                                                                        views: viewsDictionary)
        let view_constraint_VV:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-65-[top(bottom_dos)]-[bottom_dos]-10-|",
                                                                                        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0),
                                                                                        metrics: nil,
                                                                                        views: viewsDictionary)

            view.addConstraints(view_constraint_V as [AnyObject])
            view.addConstraints(view_constraint_VV as [AnyObject])

        //*** POSICION DEL TITULO
        let view_constraint_H_Titulo:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[Titulo]-0-|",
                                                                                            options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllLeading,
                                                                                            metrics: nil,
                                                                                            views: viewsDictionary)

        let view_constraint_V_Titulo:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-[Titulo]-[Texto]",
                                                                                            options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllLeading,
                                                                                            metrics: nil,
                                                                                            views: viewsDictionary)

            topView.addConstraints(view_constraint_H_Titulo as [AnyObject])
            topView.addConstraints(view_constraint_V_Titulo as [AnyObject])

        //*** POSICION DEL TITULO PARA EL CLIMA
        let view_constraintTituloClima_H:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-5-[Titulo_Clima]-5-|",
                                                                                                options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllLeading,
                                                                                                metrics: nil,
                                                                                                views: viewsDictionary)

        let view_constraintTituloClima_V:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-0-[Titulo_Clima]",
            options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllLeading,
            metrics: nil,
            views: viewsDictionary)

        bottomView.addConstraints(view_constraintTituloClima_H as [AnyObject])
        bottomView.addConstraints(view_constraintTituloClima_V as [AnyObject])

        //*** POSICION DEL TEXTO
        let view_constraint_H_Texto:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[Texto]-0-|",
                                                                                            options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllLeading,
                                                                                            metrics: nil,
                                                                                            views: viewsDictionary)

            topView.addConstraints(view_constraint_H_Texto as [AnyObject])

        //***

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    /*Funciones Extras*/
    func buttonAction(sender:UIButton!)
    {
        println("Button tapped")
    }



}
```

Answer (score 2):

The key to creating constraints with a scroll view's subviews is that the constraints are used to dictate the size of the `contentSize` of the scroll view. (Usually constraints dictate the `frame` of subviews, but with scroll view's it goes the other way around, controlling the `contentSize` that dictates the scrolling behavior.) Thus, if you want labels to not exceed the width of the screen, you don't want to just add constraints between the labels and the scroll view, but also to the scroll view's superview, too.

One way to do that is to not put the views directly in the scroll view, but rather put a "container view" (actually just a simple `UIView`, but we often call it a "container" because it does nothing but contains other view objects) inside the scroll view and then add the labels to the container view. So, if you had a scroll view with nine labels vertically laid out, you would end up with a view hierarchy that looks like so:

```
<view: 0x7fdb58b123e0; frame = (0 0; 375 667); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fdb58b079c0>>
   | <scrollView: 0x7fdb59012600; frame = (0 0; 375 667); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fdb58810ba0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fdb5880bc80>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {375, 1907}>
   |    | <contentView: 0x7fdb58813fd0; frame = (0 0; 375 1907); layer = <CALayer: 0x7fdb58814130>>
   |    |    | <label1: 0x7fdb588143a0; frame = (8 8; 359 203); text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame...'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fdb588149d0>>
   |    |    | <label2: 0x7fdb58816980; frame = (8 219; 359 203); text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame...'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fdb58816b80>>
   |    |    | <label3: 0x7fdb58817110; frame = (8 430; 359 203); text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame...'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fdb58817310>>
   |    |    | <label4: 0x7fdb58817830; frame = (8 641; 359 203); text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame...'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fdb58817a30>>
   |    |    | <label5: 0x7fdb58817e00; frame = (8 852; 359 203); text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame...'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fdb58804c10>>
   |    |    | <label6: 0x7fdb588183f0; frame = (8 1063; 359 203); text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame...'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fdb588185f0>>
   |    |    | <label7: 0x7fdb588189f0; frame = (8 1274; 359 203); text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame...'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fdb58818bf0>>
   |    |    | <label8: 0x7fdb588190a0; frame = (8 1485; 359 203); text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame...'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fdb588192a0>>
   |    |    | <label9: 0x7fdb588196a0; frame = (8 1696; 359 203); text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame...'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fdb588198a0>>
```

To get this laid out correctly, there are three sets of constraints to add:

1. Layout the scroll view with respect to its superview (in this case, the view controller's root view):

   ```
   view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[scrollView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
   view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[scrollView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
   ```
2. Next, layout the content view with respect to scroll view's `contentSize`:

   ```
   scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[contentView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
   scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[contentView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
   ```
3. Specify that the `contentView` should be the same width as the scroll view's superview (`view`):

   ```
   view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[contentView(==view)]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
   ```

   Note, although the `contentView` is subview the `scrollView`, this constraint is added to the scroll view's superview, because this constraint refers to that superview's width.

   Also note that if you want, you can actually combine this constraint with the horizontal constraint listed in point 2, above, but I've separated it here to try to make it as clear as possible.
4. Finally, now define the labels' constraints with respect to the content view:

   ```
   view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-[label1]-[label2]-[label3]-[label4]-[label5]-[label6]-[label7]-[label8]-[label9]-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))

   view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[label1]-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
   view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[label2]-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
   view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[label3]-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
   view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[label4]-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
   view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[label5]-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
   view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[label6]-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
   view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[label7]-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
   view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[label8]-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
   view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[label9]-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
   ```

   Note, that vertical constraint defines not only the distance from the first label and the top of the content view, but also the distance from the last label to the bottom of the content view.

But the key point here is the combination of point 2 (which says "make the `contentSize` of the scroll view the size of this new 'content view'") and point 3 (which says "but make the 'content view' no wider than the screen). If you don't do both of those steps, you won't get the vertical scrolling that you appear to be looking for.

Also note that if you want label to resize automatically for you, you can set `numberOfLines` to zero, and the label's intrinsic size will change to fit the text.

Clearly, your view hierarchy isn't quite like this (you have the two bottom views and the like), but I'm illustrating the basic concept of how to get scroll view's to layout correctly with auto layout constraints.